# How can I set the iOS Springboard wallpaper to a different image than the lock screen wallpaper without jailbreaking?

Tags: ios, springboard

How can I set the iOS 5 Springboard wallpaper to a different image than the lock screen wallpaper *without* jailbreaking?  The answer may very well be "you can't." I just want to know for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After going to the Wallpaper section from within Settings.app and choosing an image;

- On the iPad, there are 'Set Lock Screen', 'Set Home Screen', and 'Set Both' buttons on the top of the screen while previewing the image.
- On the iPhone, a menu pops up asking whether you'd like it on the Lock Screen or Home Screen, or Both, after tapping 'Set'.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Duh, I should have just tried it, I guess.  Thanks.